# (xlib) how "mywm" can catches a window opened before itself?

Tags: linux, xlib, xorg, window-managers

I have in my ".xinitrc" :

```
xterm &
mywm
```

in mywm I use [XQueryTree](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/window-information/XQueryTree.html) to get the list of all windows children of root. I don't get the window of xterm. I need to do that to add my titlebar to windows opened before the wm.

My question is, how mywm can detect this window ?

actually, XQueryTree can detect the window, but I have to add a sleep of few seconds before calling XQueryTree.
it's tricky, there is a better way than just forced mywm to sleep a while ?

```
struct Client{
        Window                  frame/*frame*/;
        Client                 *next; // next client
        Client                 *previous; // previous client

};

void addClient(...){
        Client *client;
        client = (Client *)malloc(sizeof(Client));
        memset(c, 0, sizeof(Client));
         .
         .
         .
        client->next = head.next;
        if(head.next != NULL) head.next = client;
        client->previous = &head;
        head.next = client;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  .
  .
  .
  while(continue) {
    .
    .
    .
    while(XPending(display)==0){ // as long as I don't get an event
      .
      .
      .
      XQueryTree(display,rootwin,&qr,&qp,&qc,&nc); // we got the list of the windows  
      .                                            // children of root
      . -> call addclient()
      .
    }
    .
    .
    .
    XNextEvent(display, &e);
    switch(e.type){
      .
      .
      .
    }
  }
  .
  .
  .
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok so I can't write "hi" or "greetings" at the begin of a question ?... so... "hi"

Comment: How do you detect windows opened after the wm?

Comment: I use `XQueryTree()` too, look at `while(XPending(display)==0`

Comment: I don't think it's correct to do that. Normally a WM selects `SubsreuctureRedirectMask` and listens to corresponding events. New windows appear there.

Comment: ok I will take a look of `SubstructureRedirectMask`

Comment: I recommend looking at the source of twm.

Comment: :D I'm looking at the `event.c` from twm for one hour now, and I come to tell you, it helped me to use `SubstructureRedirectMask` so now I can catch windows opened before mywm, thx n.m. you got the point